# TextField focus issue SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm seeing a very strange issue that I'm unable to figure out. I'm presenting a `View` with just a `TextField`. When it's focused as if typing then I try to dismiss I'm seeing this bug. I made a simple demo of the issue below. I can't seem to solve this issue or maybe I'm doing something incorrectly. It's the same for Xcode 13.2.1 to 13.4 for iOS 15.4.1-15.4.

**UPDATED**

Tested on Xcode 13 and the issue isn't present. I submitted a bug report.

[image: Xcode 13]

I forgot to toggle software keyboard but it does in fact happen on the simulator. I didn't see this until now. I've download Xcode again, restarted my simulator and unable to find a solution to this.. I’ve tested on two real devices iOS 15.5 and 15.4.1 and seeing the same issue. I’m going to try different Xcode versions and post my findings.

Here's the issue presented in simulator. In the simulator menu I/O, uncheck "Connect hardware Keyboard.".

[image: simulator]
[image: bug]

```swift
struct TextView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                TextField("Title", text: $text)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<17) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("SwiftUI")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        sheet.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Label("Text", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            TextView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce any issue with simulator or real device

Comment: I can't reproduce either.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @yawnobleix I updated my question with new findings. Make sure your simulator uses software keyboard instead. I forgot to do so and now I'm seeing the issue in the simulator even after re-downloading Xcode.

Comment: do you really need another `NavigationView` in your `TextView`? Try removing it, see if it helps with your system. I could not replicate the problem on macos 12.5, using Xcode 13.3, targets ios-15 macCatalyst 12.3.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine doesn't matter if it's in a `NavigationView` or `Form` to  a `VStack`. The issue still remains..

Comment: certainly a very strange issue, because I cannot see it on my system.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine have you disabled "Connect hardware keyboard" in the simulator and tested then? I'm also seeing a weird issue when swiping the sheet down with a keyboard present.

Comment: yes I've disabled "Connect hardware keyboard" in the simulator.
 You could try putting your `sheet` just after the `List`,
 and try using `ForEach(0..<17, id: \.self)`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine that didn't work either, I've re-downloaded Xcode from the App Store, then the developer resources page. I'm out of ideas, I can't be the only one having this issue for Xcode 13.2.1 to Xcode 13.4.

Comment: You could try adding `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to your `NavigationView`. Otherwise out of ideas as well.

Comment: Doesn’t help either. Already have that in my main project, just wrote something bland for the demo.

Comment: Can't replicate, Xcode 13.3.1, iOS 15.4, iPhone 13 Pro simulator. Have you tried with a different simulator? On an actual device. I have seen a bunch of bugs crop up lately that have been simulator based, not code based.

Comment: Simulator and device…